# passing function as parameter and popup blocker

Tags: javascript

I got tree functions:

```
var a = function (f)
{
    // some code
    window.open("")
    f();
};

var b = function (f)
{
   // some code
   f();
}

var c = function()
{
}
```

And I'm calling the functions using a chain with anonymous function:

```
a(function () {
    b(function () {
        c();
    });
});
```

If I call the a function directly, the popup blocker does not block my popup because the window.open is triggered by a user click. But using the chain, the popup blocker blocks my popup.

How can I avoid it?

ps: It is the facebook popup, I'm not trying to do something that I'm not supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers behave differently. I think Firefox is the strictest, only allowing popups directly generated in the same event loop as the onclick. In Chrome you can have an asynchronous call in between and it will still work. - At least that's what I recall from memory.

The thing is, you have little control over it. It's up to the browser to allow the popup, or not. You could develop some heuristics for each browser but that's not ideal.

Try to find a solution that will call the `window.open` in the same even loop as that is the most likely to work (if that doesn't work it's safe to assume nothing will work). Is `a()` perhaps asynchronous? Through closure you can pass the reference `var my_window = window.open` gives on to any subsequent functions in case you need to add stuff to the DOM later.

Example:

```
var a = function (f) {
    var my_window = window.open("");
    f(my_window);
};

var b = function (f) {
   f();
};

var c = function() {};

a(function (my_window) {
    my_window.innerHTML = "hello";
    b(function () {
        c();
    });
});
```

Comment: There's a ajax call in each of then =\.

Comment: Then open the window right away (as in, **not** after the ajax call) and just pass along the reference as in my example.

Comment: The problem is: I need to server side check if the user have the facebook provider or not before open the popup. But I think your example will solve it. Thank you.

Comment: I see .. well, you can always display an error I suppose .. or check before rendering the button that generates the event.

Comment: The flow is: the user clicks a menu item (invite friends), if there's not a facebook provider, then I open the popup so the user can login into facebook. After the login is done, a method to associate the account is called and then a method to populate the friends. I ll have to change it, if the user dont have the facebook provider I'll show a button so he can click the button and open the popup. Thank you, the information provided by you is essential.